# mongodb find query and object structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, swig-template

I have a question about mongodb, if I have a collection with this models:

```
new page()
page.name -> string
page.fields -> [Field]
```

where Field are:

```
{id:...,name:...,value:...}
```

can I make a query and get a result like this:

```
page.name
page.fields.name_1 -> value_1
page.fields.name_2 -> value_2
```

ecc...so creating a model on the fly, or I need to get the entire document and then iterate fields array and create a new array like:

```
new_array.name_1 -> value_1
new_array.name_2 -> value_2
```

I need this because in frontend I need to show my value using:

```
{{page.fields.name_1}}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to use JSON/JS notation for your object models instead your custom notation? That would make it easier to tell what you're trying to do.